# weak limit problem

Tags: weak-convergence, probability-limit-theorems

Let {$Y_k$} be i.i.d. random variables on $\mathbb{R}$ with a common continuous density $f$. As we put more and more points $Y_k$ on the real line they tend to concentrate so let us spread them out by multiplying by $n$, and also look at them around the point $nc$, for some fixed $c \in R$.

In other words,for each $n ∈ \mathbb{N}$, define
$$X_{n,k} =n(Y_k −c),  1 \leq k \leq n.$$

For each $n$ let $N_n(a,b)$ = $\sum^n_{k=1} I_{(a,b)}(X_{n,k})$ be the number of $X_{n,k}$ that fall into the interval $(a, b)$. How can I find the weak limit for $N_n(a, b)$ as $n \to \infty$?

Answer (score 0):

Compute 
\begin{align}
& P[X_{n, k} \in (a, b)] \\
= & P[a < X_{n, k} < b] \\
= & P[a < n(Y_k - c) < b] \\
= & P\left[c + \frac{a}{n} < Y_k < c + \frac{b}{n}\right] \\
= & \int_{c + \frac{a}{n}}^{c + \frac{b}{n}} f(x) dx \\ 
=: & p_n
\end{align}
Note that $p_n$ is independent of $k$ so that $I_{(a, b)}(X_{n, k})$ are also i.i.d. Bernoulli random variables. Therefore $N_n(a, b)$ is a binomial random variable, i.e.,
$$N_n(a, b) \sim \text{Bin}(n, p_n).$$
Also notice that (use that $f$ is continuous and integration mean value theorem)
\begin{align}
np_n = n\int_{c + \frac{a}{n}}^{c + \frac{b}{n}} f(x) dx \to f(c)(b - a).
\end{align} 
Hence by the celebrated [Poisson approximation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_limit_theorem), 
$$N_n(a, b) \Rightarrow \text{Poisson}(f(c)(b - a)).$$

Comment: It looks like the collection $\{X_{n,k}\}_{k=1}^n$, viewed as a point process on $\Bbb R$, converges in distribution to a Poisson point process  with (constant) intensity $f(c)$.